# How can a system call invoke driver function?

Tags: c, linux, kernel, system-calls

So I am interested in having a user-level program call some kernel driver function. I am trying to do that through new syscall. I have created simple syscalls before and do understand the structure of them. However I am curious how can I call the driver/module function from syscall? I tried EXPORT_SYMBOL but it still didn't find it.

Comment: If you have successfully implemented your syscall in the kernel, you can check out `man 2 syscall` for how to invoke it from userspace. You can then write a convenient wrapper so that it appears like a regular C function. You'd only be doing this for fun, a realistic driver would use ioctl instead of a custom syscall.

Comment: I do know how to call a syscall from user space. What I am curious is how can syscall call functions in driver? They don't seem to be visible to it in kernel/sys.c

Comment: please add an example of a function you are trying to call.

Comment: It's just a function doing printk "Hello World" from drivers. Question is how to call that function from kernel/sys.c It seems not visible to them